# Preventing pages being open in a new tab/window

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that behaves very strange when the user open pages in a new tab or in a new window, causing the app to crash.

I need some javascript that can help me prevent that. So basically i'd like to block ctrl+click, middle mouse button, shift+click, open in a new tab/window from the context menu; or at least block as many as possible. I wouldn't want to block right ckick(if possible), because that is never a solution.

*N.B.: I am very new to js, so any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: I don't think this is a possible solution. What about bookmarking the page and then just opening it in a new tab. I think you need to solve the underlying issues on the page that cause the crash

Comment: There may be ways to prevent it, but it's not likely to be perfect or compatible with every browser or setup. Can you include your code that misbehaves or link to a demo? Fixing the crash might be a better idea in the long run.

Comment: Like I said, I don't expect a solution to block every way of opening a page in a new tab/window; just as much as possible. Fixing the crash is not that simple, in the sense that opening a new tab/window and doing stuff on that page can remove things from the session or modify them. And when the user tries to access them from the original page they are missing/not what was expected.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a>
```

use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com';">link</a>
```

Middle mouse click opens this location in the same tab, `right click -> open in new tab` opens `about:blank` page.

---

When you can't edit every link manually you can use this script:

```
for(var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i = els.length; i--;){
    els[i].href = 'javascript:void(0);';
    els[i].onclick = (function(el){
        return function(){
            window.location.href = el.getAttribute('data-href');
        };
    })(els[i]);
}
```

and instead of `<a href="...">` use `<a data-href="...">`.

---

Going further, you may change script above to following:

```
for(var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i = els.length; i--;){
    var href = els[i].href;
    els[i].href = 'javascript:void(0);';
    els[i].onclick = (function(el, href){
        return function(){
            window.location.href = href;
        };
    })(els[i], href);
}
```

this way links stay the same `<a href="...">`, but if user has disabled JavaScript, links may be opened in another tab/window.

Comment: the last script seems to work beautifully! Thank you, kind sir!

Answer (score 4):

Replace all < a > tags attribute to _self, that will force the browser NOT to open the hyperlink in a new tab

**2021 UPDATE:**

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('a')].forEach((el) => {
            el.target = "_self"
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the other answers are no sensible option, since some `href`s in my document are procedurally changed. This block of code works though:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if(event.ctrlKey){event.preventDefault()}
});
```