# Prevent opening a new tab when ctrl+click for location.href

Tags: javascript, href

I have a Javascript function with following code.

```
function NodeClickActions(sender, eventArgs) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Get whether user clicked CTRL key or not
    var bCtrlPressed = eventArgs.get_browserEvent().ctrlKey;
    //URL of the actions page
    var URL = "../Actions.aspx";
   //If CTRL key was pressed
    if (bCtrlPressed) {
      parent.MainPage.location.href = URL + "?PackageId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&All=" + bCtrlPressed;
        }
      else {
        parent.MainPage.location.href = URL;
      }
    }
```

I need to stop the page being opened in a new tab. Please note, event.PreventDefault(); won't do the trick unfortunately.

I understand this is due to browser behaviour rather than the code.
Any suggestion is  welcome. Regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472065/preventing-pages-being-open-in-a-new-tab-window

Comment: @Sunil that solution won't work here, I am afraid.

Comment: If you think you need to dictate what is going on in my browser in that regard, then you are likely doing something wrong to begin with.

Comment: please think twice before doing that as it can be very annoying

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most simpliest way for that, preventing click on url is much smarter then preventing pressing of CTRL/CMD buttons because functionality like CTRL/CMD + CLICK is browser functionality and cannot be overwritten (or at least I didn't have success with it)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });

});
```

depend on case where you will use you need to apply something similar for form submiting... because that is also affected with this browser functionality

**Important:** OS X users using Command + Click, never forget that

**Addition:**
Because you want to disable open in new tab/window functionality under binding "click" just do preventDefaults for contextmenu (right mouse button)

```
$("a").contextmenu(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect key of ctrl press or not .Use Jquery For event handling easly

```js
var ctrl=false;
$(document).on('keydown',function(e){
    console.log(e.ctrlKey)
}).on('click','a[href]',function(e){
   if(!ctrl){
     e.preventDefault();
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="this?one">one</a>
```

Comment: i was tested myself its working. If still not working Try with ` return false` instead `e.preventDefault`

Comment: I assume complete good faith on your part @Prasanth, But I am so sorry, it is not making any difference. One more thing, I cannot use return false as I have another path to handle. Thanks any way mate. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add listener directly on anchor tag instead of using event delegation and adding on parent element. Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rakesh_makluri/7k0osxzr/7/).

HTML

```
   <a href="https://gmail.com">Click Me</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
   {
      $("a").on('click',function(event)
      {
         event = event || window.event;
         event.preventDefault(); 
         event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      });
       
});
```

Comment: On this way you completely removing click functionality... link still must be functional just without possibility to be opened in another tab using ctrl button...

Comment: Is the debugger there intentionally? I think no